# Get precision of about 20-30 digits in C

Tags: c, floating-point

So, I'm trying to calculate a certain value to a rather large precision.  The expression in C is:

```
long double t = 2.0L+.2L*(sp)+s.missRate*50L;
```

my result is: `11.575345`

But the 'real' result is: `11.575345222971968`

I'm using long doubles, which are the largest primitive type AFAIK.  I shouldn't have to use any precision libraries to do this.  So, what C type has this kind of precision?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a display issue?  `double` should have 15-16 significant digits and your result only has 8.

Comment: How do I do that?  I'm using printf("%Lf",..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is probably precise enough, but you are printing it rounded to 6 digits after the decimal point. Increase your printing precision, like this:

```
long double var;
printf("%.20Lf\n", var); //20 digits after the radix
```

Comment: Got it, I should've been doing:

Comment: Crap, enter = submit comment... anyhow, instead of %LF you need to do %.xLF  where x is how many digits after the decimal you want.

Comment: You can edit your comments for a short time after submitting, you know :).

Answer (score 0):

The double type doesn't support more than about 16 decimal digits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). So don't count on the additonal 4-14 you mention in the title.

To get more I suggest you turn to gmplib.org